# parse string and print it in python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

i want to parse @google.com from this string

```
str = 'purple alice-b@google.com monkey dishwasher'
```

and print it

```
import re
str = 'purple alice-b@google.com monkey dishwasher'
match = re.search(r'\@\w+', str)
a=re.match(r'(@)://.*\.( )$', str)
if match:
 print(a.group())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not overwrite python types. Give your `str` variable another name than `str`.

Maybe try finding *@google.com* like this: `re.findall(r'@\w+\.\w+', your_string)`